# PL/SQL - check for memory leaks?

Tags: oracle, memory-leaks, plsql

I have some PL/SQL code that I think might have a memory leak. Everytime I run it it seems to run slower and slower than the time before, even though now I am decreasing the input size. The code that I'm suspicious of is populating an array from a cursor using bulk-collect, something like this

```
    open c_myCursor(in_key);
         fetch c_myCursor bulk collect into io_Array; /*io_array is a parameter, declared as in out nocopy */
    close c_myCursor;
```

I'm not sure how to check to see what's causing this slowdown. I know there are some tables in Oracle that track this kind of memory usage, but I'm not sure if it's possible to look at those tables and find my way back to something useful about what my code is doing.

Also, I tried logging out the session and logging back in after about 10-15 minutes, still very slow.

Oracle version is 10.2

---

So it turns out there *was* other database activity. The DBA decided to run some large insert and update jobs at about the same time I started changing and testing code. I suspected my code was the root cause because I hadn't been told about the other jobs running (and I only heard about this other job after it completely froze everything and all the other devs got annoyed). That was probably why my code kept getting slower and slower.

Is there a way to find this out programmatically, such as querying for a session inserting/updating lots of data, just in case the DBA forgets to tell me the next time he does this?

Comment: Is PL/SQL even vulnerable to memory leaks? SQL is a very high-level language and those don't usually have that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v$sessmetric is a quick way to see what resources each session is using - cpu, physical_reads, logical_reads, pga_memory, etc.

Comment: Interesting... Is there a way to see *what* object the session is using? In this case the problem was a table being updated by another process. I imagine that if it were a different table I wouldn't have had such a problem. Is there another view to join this to to see the objects in question? or even if I could just see what statement was being executed that would probably be enough.

Comment: select v$sessmetric.*, sql_text, sql_fulltext
from v$sessmetric
left outer join
(select * from v$sql where users_executing > 0) queries_running on v$sessmetric.session_id = queries_running.parsing_schema_id;

Answer (score 2):

"I tried logging out the session and logging back in after about 10-15 minutes, still very slow."

Assuming you are using a conventional dedicated connection on a *nix platform, this would pretty much rule out any memory leak. When you make a new connection to a database, oracle will fork off a new process for it and all the PGA memory will belong to that process and it will get released (by the OS) when the session is disconnected and the process terminated.

If you are using shared server connections then the session uses memory belonging to both the process but also the shared memory. This would probably be more vulnerable to any memory leak problem.

Windows doesn't work quite the same way, as it doesn't fork a separate process for each session, but rather has a separate thread under a single Oracle process. Again, I'd suspect this would be more vulnerable to a memory leak.

I'd generally look for other issues first, and probably start at the query underlying c_myCursor. Maybe it has to read through more old data to get to the fresh data ?

Comment: Workstation is Windows, server is unix (not sure which flavour). I don't know if they're shared connections or dedicated. The data which `c_myCursor` is looking at is pretty static, only gets refreshed from main servers when we request it from the DBA, and hasn't been for a while.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_plsql_dbms_profiler.htm describes DBMS_PROFILER. I suppose that the slowest parts of your code can be connected to memory leak. Anyway if you go back to the original problem, that it goes slower and slower, then the first thing to do is to see what is slow, and then to suppose memory leak.

It sounds like you do no commit between executions, and the redo log is larger and larger. Probably this is the cause that DB needs to provide read consistency.

You can also check the enterprise management console. Which version do you use? Never use XE for development, since as far as I know professional version can be used for development purposes. The enterprise management console even give you suggestions. Maybe it can tell you something clever about your PLSQL problem.

Comment: The code in question does not do any commits, but it also does not do any inserts. No updates, no deletes. The PL/SQL script that calls the suspicious code *does* have a commit. I'm not using XE. I'll have to have a look at the profiler. Our IDE is PL/SQL Developer (by Allround Automation), and I think it can automatically do profiling on scripts and the code they call, I'm not sure if it profiles what I need though. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: ...oh yeah, I suspected this code because it is one of a few new things in the changed package, but it's the only code that does any data retrievel AND it's the only code that populates an array.

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns **very much** data your collection can grow enormously large, say 10 000 000 records - that can be the point of the suspicious memory usage.

You can check this on by logging the size of the collection you bulk collect into. If it's larger that 10 000 (just a rough estimate, this depends on data of course) you may consider to split and work with parts of data, smth like this:

```
declare
  cursor cCur is select smth from your_table;
  --
  type TCur is table of cCur%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  --
  fTbl TCur;
begin
  open cCur;
  loop
    fTbl.delete;
    fetch cCur bulk collect into fTbl limit 10000;
    exit when cCur%notfound;

    for i in 1 .. fTbl.count loop
      --do your wok here
    end loop;
  end loop;
  close cCur;
end;
```

Since you said that table is declared as in out nocopy I understand that you can't directly rewrite logic like this but just consider the methodology, maybe this can help you.